# vba Dir(sharePointPath) return empty after saveAs unless manually refresh the folder

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I'm saving a excel file one share Point into text file. after the saving, I wanna check Dir(sharePointPath).

It will always return "" unless I manually refresh the corresponding folder.

the code would be like the following:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sharePointPath, xlTextWindows
ActiveWorkbook.Close
While Dir(sharePointPath) = ""
    MsgBox "not exist"
Wend
```

The reason I wanna check Dir(sharePointPath) is that I wanna open that file later

`open sharePointPath for binary access read as`

which always override the text file because open can't find the file.

what should I do to fix this problem?

EDIT:

sharePointPath = {server}\rule_books\Shared Documents\Rule books\NAME - Demo and Testing Client\Text Files\test.txt before saveAS and after close.

dir(sharePointPath) = "" before and after. occasionally dir(sharePointPath) = test.txt.

but if I wait for a while after close to excute dir(sharePointPath), it will return test.txt more often. i guess vba take some time to write and show the new file.

Comment: If you put a code break just before the `SaveAs` method, what does `sharePointPath` contain?  And what about after `Close`?

Comment: @CBRF23 sharePointPath = \{server}\rule_books\Shared Documents\Rule books\NAME - Demo and Testing Client\Text Files\test.txt before saveAS and after close. dir(sharePointPath) = "" before and after. occasionally dir(sharePointPath) = test.txt. but if I wait for a while after close to excute dir(sharePointPath), it will return test.txt more often. i guess vba take some time to write and show the new file.

Comment: I don't believe it's VBA taking time to write, more like your network taking time to update the index with that file. Try saving to a local drive and see if you get the same problem.  If not, then change it back to the network save location and try stopping the windows indexing service (you can re-enable it after this test)  - I believe in windows 7 this service is just named "Windows Search" - not sure about other versions. After this service is stopped, try running your code - do you still have the same problem?

Comment: @CBRF23 your solution makes sense to me, I tested the local save. didn't get any problem. I'm new to sharePoint, so abt stop the indexing service. do I stop the service on my local machine? or I need to stop the service on which server the sharePoint is running on?

Comment: Stop on your local machine and see if that works.  I'm not versed in the inner workings of the index service, but from what I understand the local machine has to request information from the server to construct the index, and it's the lag between when the file is created and when that request is sent out and answered that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up, and create a local tmp file on user's end machine for work around